# WordPress, deactivate password recovery link in recovery email

Tags: wordpress, email, passwords, recovery, password-recovery

How do I disable the password recovery link in a WordPress password recovery email?

The email, along with the link, is generated and sent by WordPress when you press the lost password link. WordPress says just ignore the email, but the recovery link is still active and can lead anyone to a page to reset the password to that account. I want to force that link to expire prematurely.

I have tried changing the authentication keys and salts, playing around with the account but what I don't want to do is delete the account and create a new one.

Comment: The default is to expire after 24 hours. What are you trying to change it to?

Comment: Just find the code that generates the mail and remove the code that inserts the link.

Comment: @mevius Three hours or even less, I would like to set an arbitrary time. 24 hours is just too long for something that should take no longer than five minutes.

Comment: @DaveyD lol that is the first thing that I thought of but with the next WordPress update all my changes would be overwritten.

There are also WordPress hooks that let you edit the recovery email but they wont let you touch the recovery link itself.